# Deriving the Minkowski Metric from homogeneity of space-time and the isotropy of space

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, symmetry, metric-tensor

In this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space), it says that one can derive the spacetime interval between 2 arbitrary events from the second postulate of special relativity, together with the homogeneity of spacetime and the isotropy of space.

How exactly is this done?

Comment: I think you should make your assumptions more precise. How much physical meaning for the metric/spacetime-interval do you start out with? Depending on that this might end up being a conceptually pretty difficult question.

 Also "The second postulate of SR" is I assume that  the speed of light is the same for all inertial observers? I'm not aware that there is a universally accepted "ordering of SR postulates" like there is for Newton's Axioms for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations